# Flutter GoogleSignIn java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/lifecycle/LifecycleEventObserver

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

Trying to setup social login in Flutter App using GoogleSignIn and facebookSignIn via Firebase-auth I'm getting this error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/lifecycle/LifecycleEventObserver
```

I'm using thoses packages :

```
flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.14
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.1
```

With **flutter 1.9.1 + hotfix.6**

Answer (score 0):

remove app build.gradle this code:

```
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core') {
                    details.useVersion "1.0.1"
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.lifecycle') {
                    details.useVersion "2.0.0"
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.versionedparcelable') {
                    details.useVersion "1.0.0"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```